# Header file that includes all standard C library headers

Tags: c, portability

The [Standard C Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) consists of various headers files.  Often only a few select ones are needed for given code.

Other times it is simply convenient coding to include them all in a .c file, even if that make the compilation time a bit slower.

Including all standard `<*.h>` is useful to help detect naming collisions of a `.c` file with an existing standard function, object, type, macro, etc.

**Review Goal**

How well does `std.h` accomplish the goal of including all standard header files via one `.h` file given that the set varies amongst C versions and implementations?

```
/*
 * std.h
 *  Created on: Mar 16, 2019, Author: chux
 */

#ifndef STD_H_
#define STD_H_

#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#if defined __STDC__ && defined __STDC_VERSION__

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199409
#include <iso646.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#endif

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901
#ifndef __STDC_NO_COMPLEX__
#include <complex.h>
#endif
#include <fenv.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <tgmath.h>
#endif

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112
#include <stdalign.h>
#ifndef __STDC_NO_ATOMICS__
#include <stdatomic.h>
#endif
#include <stdnoreturn.h>
#ifndef __STDC_NO_THREADS__
#include <threads.h>
#endif
#include <uchar.h>
#endif

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201710
/* None added */
#endif

#endif

#endif /* STD_H_ */
```

---

In making a set of functions and types called say `foo`, I do not recommend including all header files in a `foo.h`, yet perhaps in `foo.c`.

Sample usage

```
// foo.h  (no std.h here)
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    time_t t;
    uint32_t u32;
} foo;

void foo_this(foo *f);
void foo_that(foo *f);

#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

`foo.c` or `main.c`

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "std.h"

int main(void) {
  foo f;
  foo_this(&f);
  foo_that(&f);
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

---

The alternative spellings afforded in `<iso646.h>` seem to be a solution to a regional character set problem of years ago.  I reluctantly included `<iso646.h>` here but do see that a good candidate to exclude.  It defines macros for `and`, `or`, `xor` and others.

Comment: When I read the title, I thought "*but why*?"  Having read the description, I see what you're doing.  However, beware that that if you contravene the naming rules - which I'm sure you don't - then finding no collisions using *this* compiler, *today* doesn't guarantee anything about other builds.  Past success is no guarantee of future performance!

Comment: @TobySpeight Agree the including all `<*.h>` will not certainly detect all name collision and future ones, yet is a reasonable test today to potential discern them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your code doesn't cover "freestanding implementations" (embedded systems or OS). You could check for `#if __STDC_HOSTED__ == 0` and reduce the headers. Freestanding implementations need not provide all headers except a minimal subset, see C11 4/6:

  > *A conforming freestanding implementation* shall accept any strictly conforming program in which the
  >   use of the features specified in the library clause (clause 7) is confined to the contents of the standard headers `<float.h>, <iso646.h>, <limits.h>, <stdalign.h>, <stdarg.h>, <stdbool.h>, <stddef.h>, <stdint.h>,` and
  >       `<stdnoreturn.h>`

  Though of course freestanding implementations may provide other headers too, making this hard to fulfil without a specific implementation in mind.
- Style issue: you should indent everything within `#if`... `#endif` just as you would for regular `if` statements. It is also good practice to leave a comment /* */ after each `#endif` to document which `#if` is belongs to.

EDIT: proposed indention fix

```
#ifndef STD_H_
#define STD_H_

#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#if defined __STDC__ && defined __STDC_VERSION__

  #if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199409
    #include <iso646.h>
    #include <wchar.h>
    #include <wctype.h>
  #endif

  #if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901
    #ifndef __STDC_NO_COMPLEX__
      #include <complex.h>
    #endif
    #include <fenv.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <tgmath.h>
  #endif

  #if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112
    #include <stdalign.h>
    #ifndef __STDC_NO_ATOMICS__
      #include <stdatomic.h>
    #endif
    #include <stdnoreturn.h>
    #ifndef __STDC_NO_THREADS__
      #include <threads.h>
    #endif
    #include <uchar.h>
  #endif

  #if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201710
    /* None added */
  #endif

#endif /* #if defined __STDC__ && defined __STDC_VERSION__ */

#endif /* STD_H_ */
```

Comment: Please post a sample `#` indent.  I have tried various styles, `  #if bar` (my auto formatter (Eclipse) keeps shifting them left ) and `#  if bar` which looks _odd_.  Perhaps you have another?

Comment: @chux Posted. After trying some 30+ different, magic IDEs including GNU indent, I'm convinced that mankind will never develop intelligent AI. So I tend to fall back to good ole spacebar :)

Comment: Thanks for the `__STDC_HOSTED__` idea.  I'll need to dig deeper into that.

Answer (score 4):

With this suggested usage:

> ```
> #include "foo.h"
> #include "std.h"
> ```

then any macros defined in `"std.h"` (and not used in the rest of the `main`) won't break the program.  Swapping these round:

```
#include "std.h"
#include "foo.h"
```

solves that problem, but then fails to diagnose missing includes in `"foo.h"`.