# Portable noreturn in C/C++ between compilers

Tags: c++, c, macros, portability

I'm writing a C/C++ (intended to also be valid C code) for having a noreturn macro variable as widely portable as possible between C and C++ compilers.

```
#ifndef __has_include
#define __has_include(library) 0
#endif

#if __has_include(<stdnoreturn.h>)
#include <stdnoreturn.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<stdnoreturn.h>) || defined(__cplusplus)
// `noreturn` is defined by C++, is available in the stdnoreturn.h standard 
// library header for compilers that implement it.
// Uses `noreturn` if available.
#define BLK_NORETURN noreturn
#else
// Evaluates `BLK_NORETURN`.  The GNU C library supports it via an
// `__attribute__` hint, while Microsoft MSVC can be hinted using `__declspec`.
#ifndef BLK_NORETURN
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define BLK_NORETURN __declspec(noreturn)
#elif defined(__clang__)
#define BLK_NORETURN _Noreturn
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#define BLK_NORETURN __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
#define BLK_NORETURN
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

Also, this is intended to be portable all C and C++ standards.

Comment: "this is intended to be portable all C and C++ standards" I don't think that's possible since the feature wasn't present back in the days. Well-written, modern code uses stdnoreturn.h and does not rely on non-standard compiler extensions.

Comment: As for code review... you should use indention for nested `#if #elif #else #endif` so that they can be read by humans.

Comment: @Lundin That's like the whole point. It is intended to be portable in the sense that the macro should just be defined as empty in the case the feature can't be obtained in any other way. Non-standard compiler extensions are OK and may be helpfull, as long as they are handled carefully.

Comment: @Lundin Also, my code uses stdnoreturn.h in the vast majority of cases, but the point is that in order to be as widely compatible as possible it should not rely on any standard header.

Comment: @Lundin non-indented macros are LLVM code style

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The code can't be optimized, and the only review I can see is that the code isn't indented and you don't want to accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Lundin Concerning indentation, which I prefer to only use automated fools for,  I found with Eclipse IDE the `  #if ...` auto formats to `"if ...`, yet `#  if ...` remains as is.  Do you find `#  if ...` an acceptable way to indent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**... intended to be portable all C and C++ standards.**

The first `#` branching deserves to be based on the C/C++ revision and not compiler specific tests.  Example: if code is using C11, use the `_Noreturn` keyword.
([Sample](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/216119/29485) of C revision processing.)

After tests for revisions of C/C++ that support *noreturn* fail, then begin your `#ifndef __has_include ...`.

Comment: Thanks. I also leave a reference to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646582/when-should-the-function-attribute-noreturn-be-used-in-c) for future readers